# In the NBA, if your shot gets blocked, does it still reset the shot clock?

Tags: rules, basketball, officiating, nba

I'm just wondering about when specifically the shot clock gets reset, especially in cases where the shooter gets blocked (or packed, as known informally). Is all that matters that a shot was attempted? Or does the ball have to hit the rim/backboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NBA [Rule 7](https://official.nba.com/rule-no-7-24-second-clock/) governs the shot clock.  2d describes a legal shot that must occur within the clock period:

> 2d After gaining possession of the ball, a team must attempt a field
> goal before the shot clock expires. To constitute a legal field goal
> attempt, the following conditions must be complied with:
>
> 1. The ball must
>    leave the player’s hand prior to the expiration of the shot clock.
> 2. After leaving the player’s hand(s), the ball must make contact with
>    the basket ring.

A shot that is blocked or redirected by the defense such that it does not reach the basket rim does not reset the shot clock.